# How to operate an PS eye with openCV

Tags: opencv

I would like to use the external PS eye cam to save 30 frames a second if that is possible. 
[image]

I don't know where to find guides or the code it self since I'm pretty sure it should be somewhere online.

Anyhelp would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, getting the ps3eye up and running differs depending on which OS you're running. If you're running any flavor of Debian, the drivers are already there and the code I've got below should work fine.

If you're on Windows, you'll have to find a driver for it. CodeLibrary has a driver already made, but you'll have to pay $3 for it. Link's [here](https://codelaboratories.com/downloads/).

I don't know for Mac, but a bit of digging found [this](https://github.com/inspirit/PS3EYEDriver), which might work.

Once you've got the drivers installed, you should be able to access it like any other camera.

Simple bit of code for that is below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv2\core\mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main() {

    Mat image;

    bool escnotpressed = true;

    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30); //sets framerate

    String capturePath = "C:/this/is/a/path.avi";
    Size frameSize = Size(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

    VideoWriter savedCapture;
    savedCapture.open(capturePath, VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 30.0, frameSize, true);

    if (!savedCapture.isOpened()) {
        return -2;
    }

    while(escnotpressed) { //loops
        cap >> image;
        if (image.empty()) {
            cout << "camera feed got interrupted" << endl;
            return 5; //dies if camera feed is interrupted for some reason
        }
        imshow("Image", image);

        savedCapture << image;

        int c = waitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { escnotpressed = false;}
    }

    savedCapture.release();
    cout << "Done!" << endl;

}
```

EDIT: If you've got multiple webcams on your computer, you might need to change that VideoCapture cap(0) to VideoCapture cap(x), where x gives you the right camera.